# Change Layout position from code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an app where I will be loading some images and data from a database, it should look like this:

Image______Name of user

Image______Name of user

Image______Name of user

etc..

I tried to create it just with a dummy image and some text to figure out how it works.

I create a LinearLayout, ImageView and a TextView, I add those two to the LinearLayout, and than I add that LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout.
The problem is, that all the images and text are placed in the same place, on top of each other. How can I change it so it is in the format I need?

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView hello = new TextView(this);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        String hi = "Hey";
        if(i == 0){hi = "Hello0";}
        if(i == 2){hi = "Hello2";}
        if(i == 3){hi = "Hello3";}
        if(i == 4){hi = "Hello4";}
        hello.setText(hi);
        layout.addView(imageView);
        layout.addView(hello);
        relativeLayout.addView(layout);
    }
```

I am using a for to loop it a few times just for test.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-creating-layouts-programatically/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of RecyclerView, add the items in a LinearLayout. You can also set position where to add the new item in the LinearLayout.

I would suggest you do instead is:

1. create a model object for the user details(name and picture)
2. Use ListView or RecyclerView with a simple adapter add items to an
   ArrayList of model object and notify the adapter when data is
   changed.

This way you'll be reusing the views, and that'll improve the performance much better.

for examples, you can take a look at these sample projects.
https://github.com/lokeshsaini94/SimpleAndroidExamples/tree/master/ListView
https://github.com/lokeshsaini94/SimpleAndroidExamples/tree/master/RecyclerView